# Portable shell solution to check if PID is zombied

Tags: shell, unix, sh, pid

I want to check if a PID is running (that is, exists and is not zombied).

It's really quick to do from `/proc/$PID/stat` but I'd like something more portable.

The best I have right now is:

```
( STAT="$(ps -ostat= -p$PID)"; test "$STAT" -a "$STAT" "!=" "Z" )
```

Which seems to work on BSD and Linux.  Is there a better way?

Comment: What is your plan if you identify a zombie? You could simply see if `kill -0 $PID` succeeds or fails, although failure could mean either `$PID` is a zombie or there is no such process. I'm not sure that's a useful distinction to make unless you are the operating system, though.

Comment: @chepner kill -0 on a zombie returns 0 (same as a running process)

Comment: `stat` argument for `-o` option wasn't described in POSIX 2008. So your code snippet also unportable (( +1 for interesting question

Comment: @gavenkoa The `-o` option of `ps` *is* described in the [2013 edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html)

Comment: @RolandSmith Unfortunately it doesn't define what the possible values of any field should be, and neither is the "stat" field defined.

Comment: Speaking about the shell code style alone, I would suggest `ps -ostate= -p$PID | grep -qx '[^Z]'`. (Using `state` instead of `stat` enforces a single state character to be emitted.)

Comment: This should be more POSIX-compliant: `! ps $PID |awk 'NR == 2 {exit ($3 == "Z")}'` -- The awk command looks at the second line (the first was the title) and exits true when the third column (STAT) is "Z", which is then negated (`!`) so that a Z stat or an invalid PID will return false while any other stat will return true.

Comment: I used this on Solaris 10 and it seemed to get the job done `test \`ps -p $PID -o comm | tail -1\` = "<defunct>" && echo "true" || echo "false"`

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully POSIX compliant. Tested with dash. To use it, save it with your favorite editor, make it executable (`chmod 755 foo.sh`), and run it with a PID argument.

Of course you can adapt it as needed.

```
#!/bin/sh
pid="$1";
psout=$(ps -o s= -p "$pid");
pattern='[SRDTWX]';

case "$psout" in 
    $pattern) echo "Not a zombie";;
    Z) echo "Zombie found";;
    *) echo "Incorrect input";; 
esac
```

Comment: Why use the bash-only regex rather than a POSIX sh case-statement pattern match?

Comment: I'm certainly not opposed to a POSIX sh solution, this is just what I'm familiar with. I did try it out in `bash --posix` mode and it still worked. Am I missing something? I realize bash in posix mode isn't perfect.

Comment: `[[ ]]` is very much non-POSIX, `=~` doubly so. So is use of `==`, for that matter; the string comparison operator in POSIX test is `=`, though most near-baseline-sh shells and external test implementations still implement `==` as a convenience feature since it's so cheap.

Comment: Anyhow -- `case $psout in [SRDTWX]) echo "Not a zombie" ;; Z) echo "Zombie found" ;; *) echo "Incorrect input" ;; esac` is arguably both more readable and shorter.

Comment: (I'd tend to suggest expanding your suggestion out to multiple lines, btw, for easy readability; collapsing to a one-liner is easy enough -- you could even leave the `;`s in if you want to make that particularly trivial).

Comment: @hairyyuppie could you please explain why you rolled back my edit suggesting not to set the rights of a script arbitrarily to `755` when you only need `+x`? thx

Comment: I don't know what the exact use case of this little script might be, and ultimately it's up to the user to decide what its permissions should be, but I see your point that `chmod 755` does, potentially, do more than make it executable (if the file's permissions aren't 0644 to begin with.) Nevertheless, In general, I suggest they use 0755 permissions for sh scripts of this sort. Incidentally, something like `chmod u+x` would mess with permissions even less.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO parsing the output of 'ps' is the most portable way. all the 'ps' variant out there differ a little bit in the syntax, but the overall output is good enough:

```
#!/bin/sh

process_show()
{
  ps
  ps ax
}

pid_is_zombie()
{
  pid="$1"

  process_show | while read -r LINE; do
    # e.g.: 31446 pts/7    R+     0:00 ps ax
    set -f
    set +f -- $LINE

    test "$1" = "$pid" || continue
    case "$3" in *'Z'*) return 0;; esac
  done

  return 1
}

pid_is_zombie 123 && echo "yes it is"
```

even 'ps ax' is not possible everywhere, so we must try 'ps' and 'ps ax'.